# Raven could not be contacted. We tried to access Raven using the following url

Tags: nservicebus

```
Raven could not be contacted. We tried to access Raven using the following url: http://localhost:8080.
Please ensure that you can open the Raven Studio by navigating to http://localhost:8080.
To configure NServiceBus to use a different Raven connection string add a connection string named "NServiceBus.Persistence" in your config file, example:
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="NServiceBus.Persistence" connectionString="http://localhost:9090" />
</connectionStrings>
Original exception: System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8080
```

We are using NSB 4.2.0 and Raven 2.0.2375

Five days ago we suddenly started to get this error in production from six of our production NSBs (no publishers, mixture of sagas, and non-saga endpoints). This didn't coincide with any change (although confusingly, we did a release the following day)

Even more bizarrely, one of our NSBs (a non-saga) does not appear to have this issue even though it's using the same version of NSB and Raven, and runs under the same service account.

Each effected endpoint throws this exception to our log seemingly at random but on average every 2.5 minutes.

This doesn't seem to effect the endpoints negatively - the sagas continue to be able to load state from Raven and all endpoints receive and send messages.

I'd like to work out what this problem is because it's flooding the logs at the moment.

Comment: On the server, can you browse to http://localhost:9090 ?
Is the windows service Raven DB up ? You can try to restart it

Comment: @christof13: He should try localhost:8080. That's where it's currently expected. And according to his description, it seems to fail just occasionally. Which is weird.

Comment: It seems that it has lost his configuration. Have you tried to restart the endpoint host ?

Comment: Hi yes tried to restart raven and all NSBs

Comment: Yeah I can browse Raven fine. The whole thing is working properly, it's just we're getting all these errors. But nothing is actually failing

Comment: Are you still facing the issue?

Comment: Yes I am - haven't made any progress